# Use of uninitialized final field - with/without 'this.' qualifier

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me why the first of the following two samples compiles, while the second doesn't? Notice the only difference is that the first one explicitly qualifies the reference to x with '.this', while the second doesn't. In both cases, the final field x is clearly attempted to be used before initialized.

I would have thought both samples would be treated completely equally, resulting in a compilation error for both.

1)

```
public class Foo {
    private final int x;
    private Foo() {
        int y = 2 * this.x;
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

2)

```
public class Foo {
    private final int x;
    private Foo() {
        int y = 2 * x;
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: `NetBeans` gives me an error in both cases. Are you sure?

Comment: Eclipse 4.2 (JDK7u9) does exactly what OP describes.

Comment: @PetarMinchev It compiles for me from the command line with the Java 1.7.0 compiler

Comment: OK, maybe NetBeans is smart:)

Comment: Eclipse gives me the error with java 1.7. Eclipse issue anyone?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, so, posting as a comment: It makes sense that the first one would compile, because [§17.5.2 "Reading `final` Fields During Construction" of the *Java Language Specification*, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.2) does specify what happens if you read a `final` field before it's initialized (specifically: you see the default value, in this case 0). But I have no idea why the second one *doesn't* compile. :-P

Comment: Remember, Eclipse uses it's own proprietary compiler...

Comment: `javac 1.7.0_09` also does exactly what OP describes.

Comment: Jon Skeet is laughing at us now. He will come soon like a boss:P

Comment: This *also* isn't a complete answer, so, posting as another comment: It also makes sense that the second one doesn't compile, because [Chapter 16 "Definite Assignment" of the *Java Language Specification*, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) says that a blank `final` field ("blank" meaning, its declaration didn't have an initializer) must be definitely assigned before every access, just as with local variables. (Yes, this contradicts my previous comment; but I blame the JLS for being confusing!)

Comment: we already know that eclipse compiler treats it differently than oracle jdk. anybody can test in on ibm's jdk? It probably is more a compiler quirk than something that follows from language specification.

Comment: (See also having to unqualified field names when assigning `static final`s in a static initialiser. Also consider `Foo() { Foo me = this; x = me.x; }`.)

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778650/why-isnt-a-qualified-static-final-variable-is-allowed-in-a-static-initializatio

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After a bunch of spec-reading and thought, I've concluded that:

In a Java 5 or Java 6 compiler, this is correct behavior. [Chapter 16 "Definite Assignment of *The Java Language Specification*, Third Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/defAssign.html) says:

> Each local variable [(§14.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#5920) and every blank `final` [(§4.12.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#10931) field [(§8.3.1.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#35962) must have a *definitely assigned* value when any access of its value occurs. An access to its value consists of **the simple name of the variable** occurring anywhere in an expression except as the left-hand operand of the simple assignment operator `=`.

(emphasis mine). So in the expression `2 * this.x`, the `this.x` part is *not* considered an "access of [`x`'s] value" (and therefore is not subject to the rules of definite assignment), because `this.x` is not the simple name of the instance variable `x`. (N.B. the rule for when definite assignment occurs, in the paragraph after the above-quoted text, *does* allow something like `this.x = 3`, and considers `x` to be definitely assigned thereafter; it's only the rule for accesses that doesn't count `this.x`.) Note that the value of `this.x` in this case will be zero, per [§17.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.5.2).

In a Java 7 compiler, this is a compiler bug, but an understandable one. [Chapter 16 "Definite Assignment" of the *Java Language Specification*, Java 7 SE Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) says:

> Each local variable ([§14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)) and every blank `final` field ([§4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), [§8.3.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2)) must have a *definitely assigned* value when any access of its value occurs.
>
> An access to its value consists of the simple name of the variable **(or, for a field, the simple name of the field qualified by `this`)** occurring anywhere in an expression except as the left-hand operand of the simple assignment operator `=` ([§15.26.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)).

(emphasis mine). So in the expression `2 * this.x`, the `this.x` part *should* be considered an "access to [`x`'s] value", and *should* give a compile error.

But you didn't ask *whether* the first one *should* compile, you asked *why* it *does* compile (in some compilers). This is necessarily speculative, but I'll make two guesses:

1. Most Java 7 compilers were written by modifying Java 6 compilers. Some compiler-writers may not have noticed this change. Furthermore, many Java-7 compilers and IDEs still support Java 6, and some compiler-writers may not have felt motivated to specifically reject something in Java-7 mode that they accept in Java-6 mode.
2. The new Java 7 behavior is strangely inconsistent. Something like `(false ? null : this).x` is still allowed, and for that matter, even `(this).x` is still allowed; it's only the specific token-sequence `this` plus `.` plus the field-name that's affected by this change. Granted, such an inconsistency already existed on the left-hand side of an assignment statement (we can write `this.x = 3`, but not `(this).x = 3`), but that's more readily understandable: it's accepting `this.x = 3` as a special permitted case of the otherwise forbidden construction `obj.x = 3`. It makes sense to allow that. But I don't think it makes sense to reject `2 * this.x` as a special forbidden case of the otherwise permitted construction `2 * obj.x`, given that (1) this special forbidden case is easily worked around by adding parentheses, that (2) this special forbidden case was allowed in previous versions of the language, and that (3) we still need the special rule whereby `final` fields have their default values (e.g. `0` for an `int`) until they're initialized, both because of cases like `(this).x`, and because of cases like `this.foo()` where `foo()` is a method that accesses `x`. So some compiler-writers may not have felt motivated to make this inconsistent change.

Either of these would be surprising — I assume that compiler-writers had detailed information about every single change to the spec, and in my experience Java compilers are usually pretty good about sticking to the spec exactly (unlike some languages, where every compiler has its own dialect) — but, well, *something* happened, and the above are my only two guesses.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR you are missing that ruakh says that it shouldn't compile (due to spec change for Java 7), but do compiles because of a bug in Java 7 compiler

Comment: @irreputable: Yup, looks like another consequence of the same bit of language legalese. Thanks for the link!

Comment: when a programmer accesses `this.x`, usually he thinks it has been assigned; therefore if it's not actually the case, a compiler warning/error would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the extensive explanation! I haven't been looking a lot into the depths of the JLS specs myself, I have to say. Experienced it on Java 6 compiler, btw

Comment: Coming here off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240215/java-compiler-allows-accessing-uninitialized-blank-final-field-using-this-keyw) question. This behavior still occurs in Java 1.8.0_05 for both `javac` and Eclipse's compiler. Seems to be a strangely persistent bug...

Comment: [Eclipse bug 480989](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480989) filed from this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `this` in the constructor, **compiler is seeing** `x` as a member attribute of `this` **object (default initialized)**. Since `x` is `int`, it's default initialized with `0`. This makes compiler happy and its working fine at run time too.

When you don't use `this`, then  compiler is using `x` declaration directly in the lexical analysis and hence it complains about it's initialization (**compile time phenomenon**).

So It's definition of `this`, which makes compiler to analyze `x` as a member variable of an object versus direct attribute during the lexical analysis in the compilation and resulting into different compilation behavior.

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how your quote explains this.

Comment: @Pablo: What I am trying to say is: `this` technical refers the object instance. Then when you access `x` through `this`, it uses the default initialization of `x`.

Comment: I get this _"`this` technical refers the object instance"_. But I don't see how the second part _"Then when you access x through `this`, it uses the default initialization of x"_ follows from your quote.

Comment: I have always thought (as I learnt in some SCJP book) that `this` is implicit when not written =/.

Comment: `x` being an instance variable, accessing it with or without `this` should not yield different behaviors, no?.

Comment: @YogendraSingh and if instead we use `int y = 2 * 0;` and inspect x, it also has 0, even if we are not using `this` anywhere in the code. The debugger doesn't prove that your explanation is correct. X has to be initialized to 0 because is a primitive int value, those are always initialized to 0.

Comment: @YogendraSingh my second question is just that _"Then when you access x through `this`, it uses the default initialization of x"_ doesn't follow from _"When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed"_.

Answer (score -1):

I think the compiler estimates that writing this.x implies 'this' exists, so a Constructor has been called (and final variable has been initialized). 
But you should get a RuntimeException when trying to run it

Answer (score -1):

I assume you refer to the behaviour in Eclipse. (As stated as comment a compile with javac works).

I think this is an Eclipse problem. It has its own compiler, and own set of rules. One of them is that you may not access a field which is not initialized, although the Java-commpiler would initialize variables for you.

Comment: But why the second one doesn't compile then? A compile with javac works in the first case only.

Comment: -1 this is not an Eclipse problem. `javac` exhibits the same behaviour.