# Access to final field via getter before its initializing

Tags: java, compiler-errors

First of all, this question has forward relation to these nice questions:

1) [Use of uninitialized final field - with/without 'this.' qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864464/use-of-uninitialized-final-field-with-without-this-qualifier)

2) [Why isn't a qualified static final variable allowed in a static initialization block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778650/why-isnt-a-qualified-static-final-variable-allowed-in-a-static-initialization-b)

But I will ask it in slightly another angle of view. Just to remember: mentioned questions above were asked about access to `final` fields using keyword `this` in `Java 7`.

In my question there is something similar, but not the same. Well, consider the following code:

```
public class TestInit {
    final int a;
    {
        // System.out.println(a);   -- compile error
        System.out.println(getA());
        // a = a;                   -- compile error
        a = getA();
        System.out.println(getA());
    }
    private int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestInit();
    }
}
```

And output is:

```
0
0
```

As you can see there are two unclear things here:

1. There is another legal way to access non-initialized `final` field: using its getter.
2. Should we consider that an assigment `a = getA();` as **legal** for blank final field and that it will always assign to it its default value like for non-`final` field according to `JLS`? In other words, should it be considered as expected behaviour?

Comment: The questions you linked have the rules set out by the JLS. They don't say anything about invoking methods so those are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really running into is the inference ability of the compiler.
For your first compiler error, that fails because the compiler definitely knows a is not assigned. Same with the second a=a (you can't assign from a because it's definitely not assigned at that point).
The line that works a=getA() is a first, single, definite assignment of a, so that's fine (regardless where the value comes from; the implementation of getA() doesn't matter and isn't assessed at this point).

The method getA() is valid and can return a because the instance initializer has definitely assigned a value to a.

It makes sense to a human looking at it, but it's not an inference built into the compiler. Each block, independently evaluated, is valid.

Comment: Which "static initializer"? Sorry, but what you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, instance initializer (I've edited to correct).