# Java access to a field

Tags: java, field

In JLS 8:

> In **16**:
>
> An access to its value consists of the simple name of the variable (or, for a field, the simple name of the field qualified by this).

And we know that a final blank field cannot be accessed until it is definitely assigned.

So from 1 and 2 we deduce that we cannot access the final blank field with simple name qualified by this.

But

this code compiles fine:

```
public class Test {
   final int y;
   final int z = this.y;  
   { y = 1; 
   }
}
```

But it's error if we put  final `int z = y`;

Where is the problem?

Comment: "*And we know that a final blank field cannot be accessed until it is definitely assigned*" not quite: http://ideone.com/04u069 we can assign it, `final` simply mean that it can be reassigned only once from its default value in constructor/initialization block.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it has something to do with when the static initialization block is run? Or perhaps because on the JVM level this.y =/= to y as in it is treated differently by the JVM. I suspect it is something to do with the order things are initialized by java and JVM specific peculiarities.

Comment: You should have carried on with your example and checked out what value `z` now has. It might have led you to the answer :)

Comment: @Ingo Okay, now I'm curious. What would z equal? And why?

Comment: My guess? z = null, whereas in the first bit z = an object reference.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans `z` will be `0` as it is default value of `int` type field which will be given when `new` operator will finish its work and then will call proper constructor (which will initialize it to proper value).

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans As Pshemo said, it will be `0` since that's the default value (primitives cannot be `null`). By the way, Java 8 doesn't seem to compile this anymore.

Comment: Ahhh.... Is this an autoboxing peculiarity? As in, the rawtype int has no default, but the conversion to a java object has a default of 0?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like I have it backwards.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by: "As in, the rawtype int has no default". If you take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html you will find all default values for each type like `0` for `int`.

Comment: It fails to compile for me javac 1.8.0_40 on Fedora 21. - "Test.java:3: error: variable y might not have been initialized".

Comment: @Quirliom Yes, but it compiles pre-Java 8.

Comment: What version of Java? Doesn't compile on Java 8. http://ideone.com/Cd2szc

Comment: @Quirlion Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't different IDE's sometimes use slightly different compilers which could potentially have slightly different characteristics in grey areas not covered by the JLS?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans Some IDEs use their own compiler (such as Eclipse), which have *behaviors* that deviate subtly from the specification (they have bugs). I have yet to find a "gray area" in the JLS.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans See the duplicate. This isn't a grey area. Pre Java-7 this is correct behavior, >= Java-7, this is a bug. The JLS is written with very few, if any "grey areas".

Comment: I'm not ashamed to admit that I'm not test-ready on my JLS knowledge haha. I'm a programmer, not a complier. But this is a very interesting language subtlety.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans Agreed. I certainly learned something new today :) Something like this just never comes up in real life (to me anyway). It's interesting to see how this used to be defined behavior, then a bug and is now fixed in the compiler.

Comment: I'm sure some evil CS professor out there somewhere is adding this to his test as we speak...

Comment: It doesn't compile on 1.8.0_31. Which version of java 8 are you using?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans You are not the only one to not like this kind of questions :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778650/why-isnt-a-qualified-static-final-variable-allowed-in-a-static-initialization-b#comment19033557_13778650

Comment: @Pshemo JLS says: Such an assignment is defined to occur if and only if either the simple name of the variable (or, for a field, its simple name qualified by this) occurs on the left hand side of an assignment operator.
This is why your example is fine:

Comment: @alfasin OP is using *no* version of Java 8. Several people have remarked and explained now that this compiles only in Java <= 7.

Comment: It compiles in Eclipse Luna

Comment: @IngoBürk it doesn't compile on Java 1.7.0_75

Comment: @alfasin It's a compiler bug, so it will be compiler implementation specific.

Comment: @IngoBürk I guess I misunderstood when you said: "now that this compiles only in Java <= 7" - you probably meant that it compiles only in  specific versions which are <= 7 (not on *all* of them).